# How to let a C++ compiler to know that a function is `Idempotent`

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm writing an OpenGL C++ wrapper. This wrapper aims at reducing the complex and fallible usage.

For example, I currently want the user paying only a little attention to `OpenGL Context`. To do this, I wrote a class `gl_texture_2d`. As is known to us all, an `OpenGL texture` basically has the following operations:

1. Set it's u/v parameter as `repeat`/`mirror` and so on
2. Set it's `min`/`mag` `filter` as `linear`
3. ...

Based on this, we have:

```
class gl_texture_2d 
{
public:
  void mirror_u(); // set u parameter as mirror model
  void mirror_v(); // set v parameter as mirror model
  void linear_min_filter(); // ...
  void linear_mag_filter(); // ...
};
```

Well, we know that, we can only perform these operations only if `the handle of OpenGL texture object` is currently bound to `OpenGL context`.
Suppose we have a function do this:
void bind(GLuint htex); // actually an alias of related GL function

Ok, we can now design our `gl_texture_2d` usage as:

```
gl_texture_2d tex;
bind(tex.handle());
tex.mirror_u();
tex.linear_min_filter();
unbind(tex.handle());
```

It confirms GL's logic, but it lose the wrapper's significant, right? As an user, I wish to operate like:

```
gl_texture_2d tex;
tex.mirror_u();
tex.linear_min_filter();
```

To achieve this, we must implement the function alike to:

```
void gl_texture_2d::mirror_u()
{
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, handle());
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Always doing the binding operation internally makes sure that the operation is valid. But the cost is expensive!

The codes:

```
tex.mirror_u();
tex.mirror_v();
```

will expand to a pair of meaningless binding/unbinding operation.

So is there any mechanism so that the compiler can know:

1. If `bind(b)` immediately follows `bind(a)`, the `bind(a)` can be removed;
2. If `bind(a)` occurs twice in a block, the last has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with [pre-DSA OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Direct_State_Access), and you absolutely must wrap OpenGL calls this directly with your own API, then the user is probably going to have to know about the whole bind-to-edit thing. After all, if they've bound a texture for rendering purposes, then they try to modify one, it could damage the current binding.

As such, you should build the bind-to-edit notion directly into the API.

That is, a texture object (which, BTW, should *not* be limited to just 2D textures) shouldn't actually have functions for modifying it, since you cannot modify an OpenGL texture without binding it (or without DSA, which you really ought to learn). It shouldn't have `mirror_u` and so forth; those functions should be part of a binder object:

```
bound_texture bind(some_texture, tex_unit);
bind.mirror_u();
...
```

The constructor of `bound_texture` binds `some_texture` to `tex_unit`. Its member functions will modify that texture (note: they need to call `glActiveTexture` to make sure that nobody has changed the active texture unit).

The destructor of `bound_texture` should automatically unbind the texture. But you should have a `release` member function that manually unbinds it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do this at a compilation level. Instead, if you're really worried about the time costs of these kinds of mistakes, a manager object might be the way to go:

```
class state_manager {
    GLuint current_texture;
    /*Maybe other stuff?*/
public:
    void bind_texture(gl_texture_2d const& tex) {
        if(tex.handle() != current_texture) {
            current_texture = tex.handle();
            glBindTexture(/*...*/, current_texture);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    state_manager manager;
    /*...*/
    gl_texture_2d tex;
    manager.bind(tex);
    manager.bind(tex); //Won't execute the bind twice in a row!
    /*Do Stuff with tex bound*/

}
```